# I want to make 3 text blocks for each row in Listbox.

Tags: windows-phone-7

```xml
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Width="479" Height="50">
                <StackPanel.Background>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="images/blue_cell.png" Stretch="Fill" />
                </StackPanel.Background>
                <TextBlock x:Name="section" Text="{Binding FallbackValue=day}" Foreground="White" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Visibility="Visible" />
             </StackPanel>
         </DataTemplate>
     </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
 </ListBox>
```

I want to make 3 text blocks for each row in `listbox`. Every `textBlock` contains a value from a list which I define. It's item in a class.

The problem when I bind the data using `fallbackvalue` is, it returns to me the item of the listbox, not only the day.

Example: listBox row contains name and day. I want a day in textbox and day in another text box in the same row of the listbox but diffrent textblocks. Can any one help?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're confused about what the `FallbackValue` is for. It is a string shown when the binding fails.

Assuming you're biding to a collection of objects that look a bit like this:

```
class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Day { get; set; }
}
```

You could create something like what you're after with:

```
<ListBox> 
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate> 
        <DataTemplate> 
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"> 
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Day}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Day}" /> 
            </StackPanel> 
        </DataTemplate> 
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate> 
</ListBox>
```

Comment: I did but doesn't work it's back empty textblocks is there another way to bind ??

Comment: @loleana what are "back empty textblocks"? Can you update your question with a complete repro of your issue and a mockup of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: //class1.cs contain: class class1{public string name{get; set;}  public string day{get;set;}}                                             //page1.cs contain: data2.Add(new AbsenceClass(absenceclss.time, absenceclss.isExcused, absenceclss.late, absenceclss.day, absenceclss.courseCode, absenceclss.campus,absenceclss.section,absenceclss.courseName,absenceclss.activity)); //data2 is alist.

Comment: i want to take the values from the list to list box in page1.xaml.cs  listBox1.Items.Add(class1.day+class1.name);                              page1.xaml:<ListBox> 
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate> 
        <DataTemplate> 
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"> 
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Day}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Day}" /> 
            </StackPanel> 
        </DataTemplate> 
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate> 
</ListBox>